# PSQL - Find all values and make unique based on non unique values in another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a view with multiple columns and need to update the values in column CHILD so that for every distinct value in column PARENT there is unique value in column CHILD. If not, update by adding a few characters to the value in Child before the '-'.

Example: Initial table

| ID | PARENT | CHILD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC - 123 | BBB - 364 |
| 2 | ABC - 123 | BBB - 364 |
| 3 | GHI - 789 | BBB - 364 |
| 4 | JKL - 343 | NNN - 679 |
| 5 | MNO - 524 | NNN - 679 |
| 6 | PQR - 785 | YYY - 678 |
| 7 | STU - 765 | MMM - 687 |

Final result:

| ID | PARENT | CHILD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC - 123 | BBBA - 364 |
| 2 | ABC - 123 | BBBA - 364 |
| 3 | GHI - 789 | BBB - 364 |
| 4 | JKL - 343 | NNNQ - 679 |
| 5 | MNO - 524 | NNN - 679 |
| 6 | PQR - 785 | YYY - 678 |
| 7 | STU - 765 | MMM - 687 |

Answer (score 0):

You should write a function in postgresql (PlPgsql) that makes use of `cursor` to process each distinct row value in PARENT table, and iterate in a loop to update the value in CHILD column. You may need to add alphabet and numerals to make the values unique. Read this [article](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-cursor/) on how to use cursors to iterate row by row and do some updates to the tuples in your table.

Comment: Thanks for the tips I've reviewed the linked article. Do you have an idea how that would look to help get me started?

Comment: SO best practice is that you try out first and seek help when unable to resolve or get any errors. Refer this SO [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how you should create reproducible code.